# How do I get the English United States international keyboard layout on my MacBook?

Tags: keyboard

I'm used to using Microsoft's US International keyboard layout on Windows :

[image]

Is there a way I can get the same keyboard layout on macOS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to system preferences/keyboard/input sources and use the plus and add buttons to activate the keyboard called US International PC.  Then select that in the "flag" menu at the top right corner of the screen.

If you must have the Windows version of what the Option/Alt key does, try [this custom layout](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wpi1kat7gmeifj3/Win%20US%20Intl.keylayout?dl=0).